# Showing date with specified format

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to show a date in this format: `Saturday, March 9, 2013 at 10:00pm` in c#. Can you help me in achieving that?

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime.ToString(??)
```

Comment: First google search result for "datetime c# format": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The format you want is something like the following format string

`dddd, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mmtt`

Live example: http://rextester.com/WUYT65966

Example code:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mmtt"));
```

Output:

```
Monday, March 11, 2013 at 08:51AM
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this format string. And see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for details!

```
string.format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy} at {0:hh:mmtt}", dateTime);
```

or the same but used as a format string for the DateTime.ToString() method:

```
dateTime.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' 0:hh:mmtt");
```

You may also specify CultureInformation if you'd like to format the result according to a specific culture (as @TimSchmelter pointed out in comments/his answer)

```
CultureInfo desiredCultur = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
dateTime.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' 0:hh:mmtt", desiredCulture);
```

Comment: Does return `Samstag, März 9, 2013 at 10:00` for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work in  any culture:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 03, 09, 22, 00, 00);
var toString = string.Format("{0} at {1}{2}", 
    dt.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    dt.ToString("hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
    dt.ToString("tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLower());
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/1JyCau)

Output(even in cultures without  AM/PM designator): `Saturday, March 9, 2013 at 10:00pm`

Comment: I see what you're pointing out - but isn't that the point of date format strings - that they localize the output?

Comment: @Jamiec: It can be desired to get the local format, but it can also be desired to force a specific format. Since OP just has shown his desired result, i've  shown a way to always get this output.